# How to setup OpenVPN server to work like a proxy

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to setup openvpn on Amazon EC2. 
To check it I'm using http://whatismyipaddress.com.

Currently I can connect to my remote server with:

```
sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/openvpnuser1.conf
```

After connection the server log has:

```
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235368 GET INST BY REAL: 176.XX.193.73:54967 [succeeded]
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235386 user1/176.XX.193.73:54967 UDPv4 READ [69] from [AF_INET]176.XX.193.73:54967: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA 117650fd 4f53ac24 d1614c31 f40cd5d1 49c86aa0 066fc87e 7e1db1fb 47321f9[more...]
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235393 user1/176.XX.193.73:54967 TLS: tls_pre_decrypt, key_id=0, IP=[AF_INET]176.XX.193.73:54967
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235405 user1/176.XX.193.73:54967 DECRYPT IV: 066fc87e 7e1db1fb 47321f94 d4f764ee
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235416 user1/176.XX.193.73:54967 DECRYPT TO: 00000008 fa2a187b f3641eb4 cb07ed2d 0a981fc7 48
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235425 user1/176.XX.193.73:54967 PID_TEST [0] [SSL-0] [>EEEEEE] 0:7 0:8 t=1497170646[0] r=[0,64,15,0,1] sl=[57,7,64,528]
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235431 user1/176.XX.193.73:54967 RECEIVED PING PACKET
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235437 PO_CTL rwflags=0x0001 ev=4 arg=0x55687fb01180
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235441 PO_CTL rwflags=0x0001 ev=5 arg=0x55687fb01068
Sun Jun 11 08:44:06 2017 us=235448 I/O WAIT TR|Tw|SR|Sw [8/142628]
```

Also the client raised additional interface & gained IP address (ifconfig):

```
tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.0.0.6  P-t-P:10.0.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So, I assume that openvpn connection has been established. But unfortunately the http://whatismyipaddress.com still shows my (client) real IP add.

---

Client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 52.XX.48.224 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/user1.crt
key /etc/openvpn/user1.key
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ccd/ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
```

Server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/ServerV1.crt
key /etc/openvpn/ServerV1.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ccd/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status ServerV1-status.log
log /var/log/ServerV1.log
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
push "redirect-geteway def1"
push "dhcp-options DNS 8.8.8.8"
comp-lzo
verb 15
```

Server forwarding enabled

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
1
```

iptables edited with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  ip-10-0-0-0.eu-central-1.compute.internal/24  anywhere
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a typo in your server config:

```
    push "redirect-geteway def1"
```

should be

```
    push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

and that could very much be the reason the client is not setting a default route through the tunnel once it is established.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I had some more typos "push "dhcp-optionS DNS 8.8.8.8""

Comment: Weird fact that there is no much error reporting about that... I have been bitten by this before, and also lost *lots* of time until finding it out.

Answer (score 2):

Hrm.  I think you might want to be a little more explicit in your iptables config.

```
#Allow new OpenVPN connections from the outside
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
# Allow all tun interfaces to talk to me
iptables -A input -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
# And to talk through me
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

At the top of your conf should fix you up...your default policy everywhere is accept, and your masquerade line looks ok to me...your traffic isn't passing over the tunnel once it's negiotaited (0 RX/0 TX), because you haven't added anything to your input chain....